# Program for mp3 player not working

Tags: mp3

```
#include <conio.h>
#include "inc/fmod.hpp"

FSOUND_SAMPLE* handle;

int main ()
{
   // init FMOD sound system
   FSOUND_Init (44100, 32, 0);

   // load and play mp3
   handle=FSOUND_Sample_Load (0,"my.mp3",0, 0, 0);
   FSOUND_PlaySound (0,handle);

   // wait until the users hits a key to end the app
   while (!_kbhit())
   {
   }

   // clean up
   FSOUND_Sample_Free (handle);
   FSOUND_Close();
}
}
```

This programme is not compiling in dev c++.

> ERROR-2   24  E:\coding softwares\dev c++\Dev-Cpp\Untitled1.cpp   [Error] inc/fmod.hpp: No such file or directory

Comment: The included file is missing, so you have to check your folder if it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Well as the compiler already told you, the header you are trying to reference does not exist(at that location).

Check if you typed the name right.